# CSS row heights cannot be restricted when using grid-auto-rows

Tags: css

The container with the grid has this css:

```
.container {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(0, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Then each "cell" in the grid has this:

```
.item {
    user-select: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

... inside each item is another grid with 3 rows:

```
.item-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 20px 20px 1fr;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

then inside those rows, it's just text.

The problem is when the text on the 3rd row is very long (`1fr` - dynamic height) ... the item grows, the overall container grows and nothing seems to be able to stop it.

Comment: Provide a full snippet please to help us to help you

Comment: ‘nothing seems able to stop it’. I cant see anything trying to limit this in xthe code given - what have you tried?

Comment: A Haworth - you can't see the overflow tags?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the inner rows to wrap, you may want the `overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;` combo on each of them.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 0.5em;
}

.item {
    user-select: none;
}

.item-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">
      <span>Just Text Row 1</span>
      <span>Just Text<br> Row 2</span>
      <span>Just Text Row 3 but, like, a lot of text that overflows? Lorem Ipsum etc. etc.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">
      <span>Just Text Row 1</span>
      <span>Just Text Row 2</span>
      <span>Just Text Row 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">
      <span>Just Text Row 1</span>
      <span>Just Text Row 2</span>
      <span>Just Text Row 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do want the inner rows to wrap, that's a key aspect here.

Comment: @JamesHarcourt Alright then, so it's just about the column growing in size? I updated the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in the end by simply adding this to the parent div of the container (of the parent shown in the question):

```
min-height: 0;
```